# compare jquery timepicker values

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, timepicker

have timepricker set for 24hr as followers:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.timepicker').timepicker({ 
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm', 
        minTime: '04:00',
        interval: 10,
        scrollbar: true,
        dynamic: true
    });
});
```

I have two field to obtain start and finish times

```
<input type="text" class="timepicker" name="travelstart" id="travelstart" placeholder="Travel Start" style="width:25%"> 
<input type="text" class="timepicker" name="travelfinish" placeholder="Travel Finish" style="width:25%" readonly/>
```

need some way of validating that finish time is later than start time.
something along the lines of:

```
var ts = document.getElementById('travelstart')
var fs = document.getElementById('travelfinish')
if (ts.value => fs.value) { return false }
```

Comment: What timepicker you're using and what `.value` returns?

Comment: Is that code not working? Because you're using 24-hour time, they should compare as strings fine...

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is convert the time to a single unit and compare them. Since it's just a 24h timepicker, we can use minutes here:

```
var ts = document.getElementById('travelstart').value;
var fs = document.getElementById('travelfinish').value;
var startTime, endTime, timeArr;
// split the hours and minutes
timeArr = ts.split(':');
// Hours is in timeArr[0]; minutes in timeArr[1];
startTime = (timeArr[0] * 60) + +timeArr[1];
// do the same for end time:
timeArr = fs.split(':');
endTime = (timeArr[0] * 60) + +timeArr[1];
// Now you can compare them
return startTime >= endTime;
```

Comment: Yep; forgot that, thanks. Update the code to cast `timeArr[1]` to a number.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using this [timepicker jQuery plugin](http://timepicker.co/options/).

First of all if you call just `document.getElementById('travelstart').value` it returns time in format `"04:00 AM"` which is probably not what you want so better use:

```
$('#options-change-event').timepicker().getTime()
```

to get an actual JavaScript Date object.

Then convert both times to timestamps and then compare it:

```
var tsDate = $('#options-change-event').timepicker().getTime();
var tsMinutes = 60 * tsDate.getHours() + tsDate.getMinutes();

// ... the same with the seconds timepicker

return tsMinutes > tfMinutes;
```